# sftp two files in a command line

Tags: linux, bash, sftp, ksh

Experts

I'm trying to send two files in a single sftp command line. right at the moment, I can only send 1 file when using the command line.

```
 sftp host file1
```

but I'm looking for

```
 sftp host file1 file2
```

I have to do that on 4 differents servers every day with different username.

Thanks

Comment: seriously down vote, pffffff

Comment: Do you wish to use sftp or scp?

Comment: sftp will be better since we are already using it

Answer (score 2):

If you know what files exactly you want to send, you should use the scp utility. It can do just what you want.

```
scp file1 file2 .... user@host:/path/to/folder
```

Thanks to Neil for remembering the ":/path/to/folder" bit

To do it with different usernames you could probably script it. Something along the lines of:

```
#!/bin/bash
scp "$@" user1@host
scp "$@" user2@host
scp "$@" user3@host
scp "$@" user4@host
```

usage:    ./myscript.sh file1 file2 ... filen

Comment: Don't forget the `:` after the `user@host`, otherwise it would just stupidly try to do a local file copy to a directory called `user@host`

Comment: thanks but I have to do that on 4 differents servers every day, with a different username, is there any way to use a different username?

Comment: Updated answer for four different users